# How to make a line of code span multiple lines in R where a new-line isn't created? Picture of desired outcome included

Tags: r

I'm trying to make a comment spanning multiple lines, but want them all to be the same line.

As in, Line 1 starts a comment that goes on to cover more lines, but each new line doesn't need a new '#' and Line 2 doesn't start until the comment is done.

Picture shows what I want in lines 3 and 5
[image: image.png]

Comment: Do any of these answers solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231195/multiline-comment-workarounds

Answer (score 0):

You can use strings!

```
"
Module 4 Lecture 3: 911 call times

You have 250 datapoints of the time it takes to answer and resolve a
911 call saved in a csv file called 911TaskTimes.csv

You want...
"
```

[Here's more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131338/is-it-possible-to-have-a-multi-line-comments-in-r)